# Как правильно указать в SQL запросе уникальность по 2 столбцам, но с максимальным значением в третьем?

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня есть таблица со столбцами

1. Название марки машины
2. Город
3. Мощность машины

Значения повторяются.

Необходимо вывести уникальные значения по Марке и Городу, но с учетом, что у данной связки Мощность будет максимальна.

Например :

- Lada Москва 150,
- Lada Москва 180,
- Lada Воронеж 150,
- Lada Воронеж 90.

Должно вывести :

- Lada Москва 180
- Lada Воронеж 150.

Как это можно прописать в SQL запрос?

Использую MS SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так обычный `GROUP BY` и `MAX()`

```
SELECT
  mark,
  city,
  MAX(power)
FROM
  my_table
GROUP BY
  mark,
  city
```

Comment: А если мне необходимо указать еще другие столбцы, как с этим быть?
В select еще добавить id и т п. 
Пишет, что столбец не содержится ни в агрегатной функции и в GROUP BY.

Comment: @Fresto задавать адекватные вопросы. На ваш вопрос ответили, а мыслей ваших никто читать не умеет

Comment: Да, мой косяк, думал, что остальное автоматом всё запишу. Можете подсказать пожалуйста с остальными столбцами, если их тоже надо добавлять, но там уже уникальности не должно быть.

Comment: @Fresto использовать запрос из данного Вам ответа в качестве подзапроса для отбора записей в другой копии таблицы. Заодно решить, от какой из многочисленных записей группы с макс. мощностью брать эти дополнительные поля.